# Яндекс Диск API, вывод изображений на сайт

Tags: php, curl, yandex-disk

Подскажите, как можно с ЯД получить ссылки на изображения, которые реально можно использовать для вывода изображений на страницах сайта ().

Пробовал через [библиотеку](https://github.com/nixsolutions/yandex-php-library/wiki/Yandex-Disk#%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-httpapiyandexrudiskdocdgreferenceuserinfoxml)

```html
use Yandex\Disk\DiskClient;
//
$diskClient = new DiskClient(ACCESS_TOKEN);
$diskClient->setServiceScheme(DiskClient::HTTPS_SCHEME);

// Получаем имена файлов в каталоге
$dirContent = $diskClient->directoryContents('/Новая папка/');

$img_names = array(); // массив с именами файлов

foreach ($dirContent as $dirItem) {
    if ($dirItem['resourceType'] != 'dir') {
        array_push($img_names, $dirItem['displayName']);
    }
}

$img_priviews = array();

foreach($img_names as $img) {
 
 // Файл для которого создается превью
 $target = '/Новая папка/'.$img;
 //Сохранение превьюшки
 $size = 'XXXS';
 $file = $diskClient->getImagePreview($target, $size);

 file_put_contents('previews/'.$img, $file['body']);
 //Вывод превьюшки
 $size = '1000x';
 $file = $diskClient->getImagePreview($target, $size);

 header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
 header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
 header('Expires: 0');
 header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
 header('Date: ' . $file['headers']['date']);
 header('Content-Type: '.$file['headers']['content-type']);
 header('Content-Length: ' . $file['headers']['content-length']);
 header('Accept-Ranges: ' . $file['headers']['accept-ranges']);
 
// array_push($img_priviews, $file['body']);
}

// Вывод изображений
foreach($img_priviews as $imgs) {
 echo $imgs;
}
```

Выводит только одну картинку, а в указанную папку на сервере загружает изображения размером 50х50.

Знаю, что можно еще cURL использовать для этих целей, но под данную задачу пока не разобрался как.

P.S.: ЯД для требуется использовать, для освобождения места на сервере (фотографий достаточно много)

Comment: Честно говоря это плохая идея - очень уж медленно все будет работать. Какой у вас обьем данных вообще?

Comment: более 250 организаций которые регулярно загружают новости с фото (каждая фотка до 2Мб). точнее затрудняюсь ответить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалось решить следующим образом:

```html
use Yandex\Disk\DiskClient;
//
$diskClient = new DiskClient(ACCESS_TOKEN);
$diskClient->setServiceScheme(DiskClient::HTTPS_SCHEME);

// Получаем имена файлов в каталоге
$dirContent = $diskClient->directoryContents('/Новая папка/');

$img_names = array(); // массив с именами файлов

foreach ($dirContent as $dirItem) {
    if ($dirItem['resourceType'] != 'dir') {
        array_push($img_names, $dirItem['displayName']);
    }
}

$img_priviews = array();

foreach($img_names as $img) {
 $headers = array("Authorization: ".ACCESS_TOKEN);
 $curl = curl_init('https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/resources?path=disk:/Новая папка/'.$img.'&preview_size=300x300');
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $info = curl_exec($curl);

 $response = json_decode($info);
 array_push($img_priviews, $response->preview);
}

foreach($img_priviews as $imgs) {
 echo '<img src="'.$imgs.'" alt="">';
}
```